# what is the optimal size of bin to be chosen in radix sort?

Tags: algorithm, radix-sort

I have 10^4 numbers in the range 10^12, what is the optimal number of bins to be used in radix sort? How do we determine the best bin size in radix sort?

Comment: Well 10^12 ~ 2^40, so try 2^14, 2^10, 2^8, ... and simply measure what's fastest...

Comment: It very depend from CPU architecture and implementation. Tha simplest way, try different sizes and measure execution time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a space - time trade off. The more bins you use the more memory you need but you will need fewer passes. So it really depends how you define "optimal".

Comment: Also more bins = less time does not necessarily hold true due to cache effects and because the bins need to be traversed at the end of each pass. So the number of elements might also play an important role in that decision

Comment: Big bin can introduce additional waste of time for initialization, and of cause cache size can be missed.